# SwiftUI value in text doesn’t change

Tags: swiftui

I don’t understand why the Text Value doesn’t change. if I remove the TextField, the Text value change :/ is there something about combine or SwiftUI I am missing ?

```swift
struct ContentView2: View{
    @State private var numTouches: Int = 0
    @State private var num: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Touch me pls"){
                self.numTouches += 1 
            }
            Text("\(numTouches)")
            TextField("Hello enter a number", text: $num)
        }.onReceive(Just(num)) { newValue in
            if newValue == "" {
                self.numTouches = 0
            } else {
                self.numTouches = Int.init(newValue)!
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `numTouches` updates, and then reverts immediately back to whatever `num` is because of `onReceive(Just(num))`. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want two things first I want to write a number then touch the button and the written number increases, the other Case is If I don’t write any number the text field increase when I push the button from 0 to number of press

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that when a button is touched, it increases `numTouches`,  which causes the view's body to re-render. `.onReceive` subscribes to the `Just` publisher that immediately publishes the value `num`, which is empty `""` in the beginning, and that sets `numTouches` back to `0`.

It sounds that you have really just a single variable, which is being updated from two places:

- via `TextField`
- via `Button`'s action

So, keep it as single `@State var numTouches: Int`:

```
struct ContentView2: View{
    @State private var numTouches: Int = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button("Touch me pls"){
                self.numTouches += 1 
            }
            Text("\(numTouches)")
            TextField("Hello enter a number", 
                      text: $numTouches, formatter: NumberFormatter()))
              // .keyboardType(.numberPad) // uncomment for number pad keyboard
        }
    }
}
```